# Characters typed in gtk program are changed to something totally different while keyboard is set to french

Tags: c, windows, gtk

I am developing a Gtk application and most things work just as intended. When I type text in a GtkEntry widget all is fine while I have my keyboard set to english. But when I switch to french, all characters that I type in text entry widgets withing my gtk program are translated to something totally different. That is even if I type plain english characters with the french keyboard.

For example:
"r" becomes "¶",
"t" becomes "ŧ",
"y" becomes "←",
and "u" becomes "↓".

While using the french keyboard, all text I type in other programs comes out fine.

I started developing my program on linux and I had no problems or whatsoever at the time. I'm only getting this weird behavior since I moved the project to windows, since the intended users are on windows.

I've made searches and maybe I'm not using the right keywords or phrasing but I can't find anything closely related to my problem. Any help or hint to where I should check to solve my problem would really be appreciated.

I have installed Gtk via vcpkg, code is written in C, and using visual studio.

Thank you!

Comment: Hello! I have tried with vcpkg on Win10 but I don't have any problem. Could you explain step by step how to reproduce the issue?

Comment: I kept working on my project to finally notice characters were suddenly fine. I have no idea what I did. I rolled back my source to when the problem was present and it still was fine.  My guess is that Visual Studio put a flag of some sort and kept it. All I know is I couldn't reproduce the problem. I have also moved away from Visual Studio and I am now using msys and Mingw and all is fine. Thank you for your time and effort though.